# Very basic question about submitting data to API using SOAP & PHP

Tags: php, api, soap

Before I ask my question I want to thank everyone on stack overflow.  I'm really amazed at how helpful everyone is and how much I've learned just in the past year or so from asking questions when I'm confused.

I'm trying to use the recordSale function on this API for someone my work does business with, it's a way to record sales (hence the name):

url:  https://secure.directtrack.com/api/soap.php#
wsdl: https://secure.directtrack.com/api/soap.php?wsdl

Name: recordSale
Binding: DirectTrackWebServicesBinding
Endpoint: http://secure.directtrack.com/api/soap.php
SoapAction: http://secure.directtrack.com/api/soap.php/recordSale
Style: rpc
Input:
  use: encoded
  namespace: http://soapinterop.org//
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: recordSaleRequest
  parts:
    client: xsd:string
    password: xsd:string
    order_id: xsd:string
    sale_amount: xsd:double
    campaign_id: xsd:int

Output:
  use: encoded
  namespace: http://soapinterop.org//
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: recordSaleResponse
  parts:
    return: xsd:int

Namespace: http://soapinterop.org//
Transport: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http

So I am trying to set up the php for this and I wrote:

```
$client2 = new SoapClient("http://secure.directtrack.com/api/soap.php?wsdl", array('trace'=> true));
$results2 = $client2->recordSale(array(
                                       "client" => 'my work's client #', 
                                       "password" => "password",
                                       "order_id"  => "2",
                                       "sale_amount"  => "1000",
                                       "campaign_id"  => "16",
                                       "affiliate_code"  => "CD35",
                                       "date"  => "2009-11-17",
                                       "sale_status"  => "",
                                       "optional_info"  => "fsq2",
                                       "misc"  => "9",
                                       "record_lead"  => "1"));
echo "<pre>";
        print_r($results2);
echo "</pre>";
```

And the return value that gets printed is the number "1".  The thing is that this "1" doesn't change if I change the password or leave out required fields.  Am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: If you got answer for this and you know c# coding.can you pls give this solution in c#.bcoz i m facing same problem for same url.thanx in advance

Comment: can u please tell me what can b the value of client.pls u can tell that atleast.and password is of affiliate login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please add some debugging-statements to your code to see what's happening *on the wire*?

```
$client2 = new SoapClient("http://secure.directtrack.com/api/soap.php?wsdl", array(
    'trace'=> true
));
$results2 = $client2->recordSale(array(
    "client" => // ...
));
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($client2-> __getLastRequestHeaders());
var_dump($client2-> __getLastRequest());
var_dump($client2-> __getLastResponseHeaders());
var_dump($client2-> __getLastResponse());
var_dump($results2);
echo "</pre>";
```

This will give you some insight into the SOAP request being generated and into the SOAP response being returned from the server.

Comment: if you got answer of this,can you please help me out with this.I have same issue with direct track.I m getting 500 (Internal server error).My soap call is working fine,i have tested with my webservice,but i guess my parameter values are wrong.what can b the value of client? and password will b of our affiliate partner login password?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a single quote in there

```
'my work's client #'
```

...which should be:

```
"my work's client #"
```

Secondly, you should probably use a debugging tool (I use eclipse php for debugging but there's several out there including netbeans).  You will see more information with a debugger.

Lastly, you can see the actual XML of the request and response via:

```
$lastRequest = $client2->__getLastRequest();
$lastResponse = $client2->__getLastResponse();
```

...since you have trace turned on.

Comment: oh the single quote was just me changing my work's login and pasword so i can post it here.  Thanks for your help.